# Is there a better way to get this than multiple sub-queries, perhaps with more joins?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have several tables joined together with the purpose of determining the "best", meaning the smallest, box that a single item or a group of these items will fit in to.
Its just to get me "close enough" so I can then determine the shipping cost of that item or items by different carriers.

I have combined the two steps of 1 getting each item and its measurements via MySQl query and 2 getting the "best" box by querying the results from the first query, with one mySql query that does them both for me.
The issue now is that its too slow, I would like this query to run much faster, I have looked at optimizing indexes, but that doesn't seem to help.  I think perhaps there's a better way to structure the query to get a faster result set.

```
SELECT
Listings.PriceCodeDetail.RecNbr AS PCDRecNbr,
(SELECT RecNbr FROM Boxes 
WHERE    
  (
    GREATEST(LENGTH, Width, Height) >= GREATEST(atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemLength,atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemWidth,atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemHeight) #GreatestMeasurement
    AND LEAST(LENGTH, Width, Height) >= LEAST(atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemLength,atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemWidth,atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemHeight) #LeastMeasurement
    AND (LENGTH + Width + Height) - LEAST(LENGTH, Width, Height) - GREATEST(LENGTH, Width, Height) >= (atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemLength+atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemWidth+atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemHeight) - LEAST(atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemLength,atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemWidth,atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemHeight) - GREATEST(atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemLength,atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemWidth,atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemHeight) #MedianMeasurement
  ) 
  AND WEIGHT >= (Listings.PriceCodeDetail.QtyBreak * (Listings.ItemListingDetail.ListingQty * atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemWeight)) #TotalWeight
ORDER BY CuIn 
LIMIT 1) AS IdealBox # This finds the Longest side, shortest side and middle side and compares it to the Longest, shortest and middle of the item(s) then makes sure the weight is greater that the item(s) weight(s)
FROM
Listings.ItemListingHeader
INNER JOIN Listings.ItemListingDetail ON Listings.ItemListingDetail.HeaderRecNbr = Listings.ItemListingHeader.RecNbr
INNER JOIN Listings.PriceCodeHeader ON Listings.PriceCodeHeader.ListingRecNbr = Listings.ItemListingHeader.RecNbr
INNER JOIN Listings.PriceCodeDetail ON Listings.PriceCodeDetail.HeaderRecNbr = Listings.PriceCodeHeader.RecNbr
INNER JOIN atr_grail_live.ip_Spec ON Listings.ItemListingDetail.IPRecNbr = atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.IP_RecNbr
WHERE
Listings.ItemListingHeader.MarketplaceRecNbr = 1 AND
Listings.PriceCodeHeader.CustomerPriceLevelRecNbr IN (4,5)
AND Listings.ItemListingHeader.RecNbr NOT IN (
SELECT
Listings.ItemListingHeader.RecNbr
FROM
Listings.ItemListingHeader
INNER JOIN Listings.ItemListingDetail ON Listings.ItemListingDetail.HeaderRecNbr = Listings.ItemListingHeader.RecNbr
INNER JOIN Listings.PriceCodeHeader ON Listings.PriceCodeHeader.ListingRecNbr = Listings.ItemListingHeader.RecNbr
INNER JOIN Listings.PriceCodeDetail ON Listings.PriceCodeDetail.HeaderRecNbr = Listings.PriceCodeHeader.RecNbr
INNER JOIN atr_grail_live.ip_Spec ON Listings.ItemListingDetail.IPRecNbr = atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.IP_RecNbr
WHERE
Listings.ItemListingHeader.MarketplaceRecNbr = 1 AND
Listings.PriceCodeHeader.CustomerPriceLevelRecNbr IN (4,5)
AND (atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemLength IS NULL OR atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemLength = '')
GROUP BY Listings.ItemListingHeader.RecNbr
) # This removes from the result set any item(s) that don't have measurements and aren't part of specific groups I have defined, PriceLevel and Marketplace in this instance. 
AND atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.IP_RecNbr IN (47467))
# The last AND is only there for now to limit it to one group of items... it will not be used once this is optimized.
```

I have left some comments in there so as to better explain what I am doing. Currently this query takes about 4 seconds and returns 14 rows.
If I remove the last line that limits it to one item it would be using over 250K item combinations...so would take a LOOOONG time.

Note that each subquery runs very quickly itself, so I think I have indexes correct.

Also note that if this can't be optimized like this, I could change the structure of any of the tables to accommodate.   I was thinking I could store Boxes and Items in Length,Width,Height and actually force Length to be longest, Width to be in the Middle and Height to be the shortest side.   Would that help?

Thanks for any pointers on this.

*** Added more comments **** 
If it helps the reason I am doing all that math with the greatest and least is to determine the Longest Side, Shortest Side, and then the one in the middle (Median).  So since I have 3 values L,W,H (Length,Width,Height) and can determine the largest and smallest values in SQL, the one left over after subtracting the other two is the Median.

*** Added Table layouts ***

```
CREATE TABLE `ItemListingHeader` (
  `RecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SKU` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `MarketplaceRecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MarketplaceListingID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `MarketplaceShippingTemplateRecNbr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QtyAvailToReport` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QtyUpdated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RecNbr`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UniqueKey` (`SKU`,`MarketplaceRecNbr`,`MarketplaceListingID`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `UniqueKey2` (`SKU`,`MarketplaceRecNbr`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `RecNbr` (`RecNbr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36351 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `ItemListingDetail` (
  `RecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HeaderRecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IPRecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ListingQty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RecNbr`,`HeaderRecNbr`,`IPRecNbr`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UniqueKey` (`HeaderRecNbr`,`IPRecNbr`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `HeaderKey` FOREIGN KEY (`HeaderRecNbr`) REFERENCES `ItemListingHeader` (`RecNbr`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36344 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `PriceCodeHeader` (
  `RecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ListingRecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CustomerPriceLevelRecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CustomerNbr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RecNbr`,`ListingRecNbr`,`CustomerPriceLevelRecNbr`,`CustomerNbr`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UniqueKey1` (`ListingRecNbr`,`CustomerPriceLevelRecNbr`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `RecNbr` (`RecNbr`),
  CONSTRAINT `ListingHeader` FOREIGN KEY (`ListingRecNbr`) REFERENCES `ItemListingHeader` (`RecNbr`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=85976 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

CREATE TABLE `PriceCodeDetail` (
  `RecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HeaderRecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PricingMethod` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QtyBreak` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Floor` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ceiling` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Modifier` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Override` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AmznMod` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PackagingSqFt` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LaborMinutes` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OtherCosts` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FloorMultiplier` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CeilingMultiplier` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DiscountMultiplier` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CurrPrice` double(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RecNbr`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UniqueKey` (`HeaderRecNbr`,`QtyBreak`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `Header` FOREIGN KEY (`HeaderRecNbr`) REFERENCES `PriceCodeHeader` (`RecNbr`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=242526 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

CREATE TABLE `ip_Spec` (
  `IP_RecNbr` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Amperage` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ANSICode` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Base` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `BallastCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `BeamSpread` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `BurnPosition` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Candlepower` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ColorTemp` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ColorTemp_Filter` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Color` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Color_Filter` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `CRI` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Diameter` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Diameter_Filter` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DocumentFile1` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DocumentFile2` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DocumentFile3` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DocumentFile4` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DocumentFile5` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DocumentDescription1` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DocumentDescription2` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DocumentDescription3` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DocumentDescription4` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DocumentDescription5` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DocumentType1` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DocumentType2` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DocumentType3` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DocumentType4` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DocumentType5` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Filament` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Finish` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `GlassSize` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `GlassSize_Filter` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `HourLife` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `InitialLumens` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ImageFile` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `AddtlImage1` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `AddtlImage2` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `AddtlImage3` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `AddtlImage4` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `AddtlImage5` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `LCL` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Length` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Length_Filter` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Lumens` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Voltage` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Voltage_Filter` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Wattage` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Wattage_Filter` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ShipCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `SpecStatus` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country_of_Origin` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Contents` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `HS_Code` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Dimmable` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `Enclosure_Rated` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `Rough_Service` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `Self_Ballasted` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `Rapid_Start` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `Pulse_Start` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `Covered_Glass` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `Energy_Star` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `ROHOS` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `BallastType` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `BallastStartMethod` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `NumberOfLamps` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BallastFactor` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BallastProductTechnology` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MinimumStartTemperature` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TotalHarmonicDistortion` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmergencyBallast` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `CurrentType` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `OutputCurrent` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OutputCurrentUnitOfMeasure` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `OutputVoltage` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OutputVoltageUnitOfMeasure` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `PowerFactor` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Efficiency` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Programmable` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `MinimumWattage` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MaximumWattage` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HousingMaterial` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `LenseMaterial` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `MountingStyle` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `LightSourceType` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ReflectorType` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `IntegratedLightSource` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `PhotoCellIncluded` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `SpecsComplete` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `LocationRating` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ItemLength` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ItemLengthUnitOfMeasure` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ItemWidth` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ItemWidthUnitOfMeasure` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ItemHeight` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ItemHeightUnitOfMeasure` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ItemWeight` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ItemWeightUnitOfMeasure` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ProductFamily` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `ShortDescription` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `LongDescription` text,
  `InternalNotes` tinytext,
  `BulletPoint1` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `BulletPoint2` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `BulletPoint3` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `BulletPoint4` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `BulletPoint5` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `WarrantyYears` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ETL` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `CE` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `UL` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `DLC` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `TCLP` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `IPRated` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `IPRating` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Standby` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `CeramicMetalHalide` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `UVProtected` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `LIFCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `EnergySaver` varchar(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `ElectricalRequirements` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `LumensPerWatt` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Disclaimer` text,
  `InputElectricalPolarity` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Atmosphere` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `BaseMaterial` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `GlassMaterial` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `DimmablePercentage` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ServiceType` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `GlassShape` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `OutputElectricalPolarity` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BeamSpreadDesc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case1Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case1Qty` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case1Length` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case1Width` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case1Height` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case1Weight` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case1GTIN` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case1EAN` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case2Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case2Qty` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case2Length` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case2Width` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case2Height` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case2Weight` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case2GTIN` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case2EAN` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case3Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case3Qty` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case3Length` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case3Width` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case3Height` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case3Weight` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case3GTIN` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case3EAN` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case4Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case4Qty` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case4Length` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case4Width` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case4Height` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case4Weight` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case4GTIN` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Case4EAN` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IP_RecNbr`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IpRec` (`IP_RecNbr`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `SpecStatus` (`SpecStatus`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii

CREATE TABLE `Boxes` (
  `RecNbr` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Length` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Width` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Height` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Weight` decimal(10,1) NOT NULL,
  `CuIn` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RecNbr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=184656 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` output for all tables in your query.

Comment: Good idea!  Thanks... I added them.

Comment: Ok, well let's figure out where to focus our attention. Try removing the subquery in your select, and re-run the query (at least twice, report only the last result.) How long does it take to execute? If very quickly, then we know that subquery is the major problem. If no change, then we know the subquery in the SELECT doesn't matter to the speed. If only some improvement, then we need to fix both that and the main query.

Comment: Break it down... got it...  Ok If I remove the Subquery in the select the query runs in .626 sec, less than a second to return the 14 rows. 
If I run the subquery on its own using a single record from the main query, it takes .226 seconds... super fast.   So perhaps the initial query of .795 without the subquery is actually the one needing optimized?

Comment: Ok this is helping!  I took the subquery part and built indexes on the Boxes table for each individual field of Length, Width,Height,Weight,CuIn and the sub query is now down to .001 seconds....  so I ran my main query again and it is now down to about a second for my 14 rows!    Now I need to keep going and make it even better, as 1 second x 250K is still too long if I can make it faster. Excellent! This is fun!

Comment: Excellent. I was going to say, .626 is not super fast for me, I like to see 0.02s or less before I call it fast. Now that we have the subquery in the select handled, we can focus on the main query. I'll post again when I have additional suggestions. (I'm switching back and forth between your question and my actual work, so I won't be able to respond again until somewhat later, most likely.)

Comment: I am going to attempt to go another route here...  If I pull in the main query as an array and then just pull in the contents of the Boxes table into another array, perhaps I can do the "query" or calculation of which box inside PHP and it will be faster?    Its worth a shot.  Thank for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your `NOT IN` where statement seems unnecessary. I suggest replacing it with

```
atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemLength IS NOT NULL
AND atr_grail_live.ip_Spec.ItemLength <> ''
```

in the main query.

This should provide the same results, but without the need for the `NOT IN` subquery, as that subquery is basically just a duplicate of your main query.

The only big savings I see after that is

```
Listings.PriceCodeHeader.CustomerPriceLevelRecNbr IN (4,5)
```

Any kind of `IN` or `OR` is generally a good place to try to speed things up, as exact matches tend to be handled much faster.

Splitting your query up into two queries, one with

```
Listings.PriceCodeHeader.CustomerPriceLevelRecNbr = 4
```

and the other with

```
Listings.PriceCodeHeader.CustomerPriceLevelRecNbr = 5
```

and then using `UNION ALL` to combine the query results may also provide some improvement.

After that, only a missed index somewhere is likely. Provide an `EXPLAIN` plan of this optimized query and I may be able to help determine where another index could be useful.

That said, you are really on top of your game when it comes to indexing. Most people looking for query optimization help don't have any concept of how indexes work, but you are an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
    WHERE  Listings.ItemListingHeader.MarketplaceRecNbr = 1
      AND  Listings.PriceCodeHeader.CustomerPriceLevelRecNbr IN (4, 5)
      AND  Listings.ItemListingHeader.RecNbr NOT IN ( SELECT ... )
```

Change the `NOT IN` to a `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`

The `WHERE` clause is referencing multiple tables, there is no way to add an index that spans multiple tables.  Anyway, have an index on `MarketplaceRecNbr`.  (More in a minute.)  And on `CustomerPriceLevelRecNbr`.

You have several inefficiencies in your indexes.  Study these rules:

- A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key is an `INDEX`.  (cf `ItemListingHeader.RecNbr)
- If you have a unique key whose columns is a subset of another unique key, the latter is automatically unique and should be changed to `INDEX` to avoid extra effort.
- `INDEX(a,b)` is unnecessary if you also have the same *beginning* columns: `INDEX(a,b,c)`.  Your case is more complex since it involves a uniqueness constraint.  `UNIQUE(a,b), UNIQUE(a,b,c)` --> `UNIQUE(a,b), INDEX(b,a,c)`
- `INDEX(a,b)` takes care of any need for `INDEX(a)`, but it does not take care of `INDEX(b)`.  That is the ordering matters.

From those rules, make a stab at a better set of indexes for each table.  I'll critique it.